# How to create a new column based on if certain strings exist in another column?

Tags: pyspark

I have a table looks like this:

```
+--------+-------------+
| Time   | Locations   |
+--------+-------------+
| 1/1/22 | A300-abc    |
+--------+-------------+
| 1/2/22 | A300-FFF    |
+--------+-------------+
| 1/3/22 | A300-ABC123 |
+--------+-------------+
| 1/4/22 | B700-abc    |
+--------+-------------+
| 1/5/22 | B750-EEE    |
+--------+-------------+
| 1/6/22 | M-200-68    |
+--------+-------------+
| 1/7/22 | ABC-abc     |
+--------+-------------+
```

I would like to derive to a table that looks like this:

```
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| Time   | Locations   | Locations_Clean |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1/1/22 | A300-abc    | A300            |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1/2/22 | A300 FFF    | A300            |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1/3/22 | A300-ABC123 | A300            |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1/4/22 | B700-abc    | B700            |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1/5/22 | B750-EEE    | B750            |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1/6/22 | M-200-68    | M-200           |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1/7/22 | ABC-abc     | "not_listed"    |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Essentially I have a list of what the location code should be e.g. ["A300","B700","B750","M-200"], but currently the location column is very messy with other random strings. I want to create a new column that shows the "cleaned" version of the location code, and anything that is not in that list should be marked as "not_listed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  regex and when condition. In this case I check if string begins with a digit `^[0-9]` then extract the the leading digits in the string. If it doesn then attribute it with not listed. Code below

```
df=df.withColumn('Locations_Clean', when(col("Locations").rlike("^[0-9]"),regexp_extract('Locations','^[0-9]+',0)).otherwise(lit('not_listed'))).show()

+--------------------+---------+---------------+
|                Time|Locations|Locations_Clean|
+--------------------+---------+---------------+
|0.045454545454545456|   300abc|            300|
|0.022727272727272728|   300FFF|            300|
| 0.01515151515151515|   300ABC|            300|
|0.011363636363636364|   700abc|            700|
|0.009090909090909092|   750EEE|            750|
|0.007575757575757575|   ABCabc|     not_listed|
+--------------------+---------+---------------+
```

With your new question, use regexp_replace

```
df=df.withColumn('Locations_Clean', when(col("Locations").rlike("\d"),regexp_replace('Locations','\-\w+$','')).otherwise(lit('not_listed')))

+------+-----------+---------------+
|  Time|  Locations|Locations_Clean|
+------+-----------+---------------+
|1/1/22|   A300-abc|           A300|
|1/2/22|   A300-FFF|           A300|
|1/3/22|A300-ABC123|           A300|
|1/4/22|   B700-abc|           B700|
|1/5/22|   B750-EEE|           B750|
|1/7/22|   M-200-68|          M-200|
|1/6/22|     ABCabc|     not_listed|
+------+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I updated the example above to show how the actual data would be like. (i.e. the desired string could include more than just numbers [0-9], but also include string, and some notations. The idea is to check whatever is in that list of "clean name". Apology for the confusion!

Comment: This a completely question from what you had asked. courtesy is you acknowledge efforts if initial question was answered as expected before asking for further help

Comment: Apology for that! Yes your answer above did answer my original question. It's my mistake for not stating clearly in the example that the desired string could include more than just numbers.

Comment: Edited, please accept and upvote, if any concerns let me know